# How to catch exceptions in constructor or overloaded operator?

Tags: c++, constructor, try-catch

So I have a class that realized fractions. I have to add catch&throw to a constructor(in case if the denominator is zero) and to the overloaded operator of dividing(in case dividing by zero). How I should realize that? But I need catch block is over this constructor because I need to stop creating this object.

```
class Rational{
public:
    Rational(const int num, const int den){
    try{  
        numerator = num;
        denominator = den;
        if( denominator == 0){
            throw invalid_argument(" den is zero ")
      }
    }
    catch (invalid_argument& e){
        cout << e.what() << endl;
      }
  }
// I mean I want smth like that
try {
    Rational operator/(const Rational& lhs, const Rational& rhs) {

        return Rational{ lhs.Numerator() * rhs.Denominator(), lhs.Denominator() * rhs.Numerator() };

        if (rhs.Numerator() == 0) {
            throw domain_error("dividing by zero");
        }

    }
}
catch (const domain_error& e) {
    cout << e.what();
}
```

Comment: [OT]: a nice trick to avoid `Rational(n, 0)` is to add constructor `Rational(int, std::nullptr_t) = delete;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put a `try`/`catch` in the constructor. If you `catch` exceptions in the constructor then the object *will* be created.

If your `denominator` is invalid, then your `Rational` object will be invalid and should not be created. The `try`/`catch` should be around the code that tries to create `Rational` object.

If you `Rational` object is allocated with `new` then the system will automatically deallocate the memory allocated for `Rational` and then rethrow the exception for you to `catch`.

Comment: Do I have to use try&catch block all-time when I want to work with that class?

Comment: It's up to you where exactly you put the try/catch. For example, if the denominator is being read in from user input, then you need to catch the exception at that level, and inform the user they've made a mistake.

If the denominators are being read in sequentially from a file, then but the catch at a point where you can log the error and move onto the next file entry.

Comment: But you certainly want to have a catch somewhere. Don't leave the exception completely unhandled as this will cause program termination.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand your question. The only way to prevent a class from being constructed is by throwing an exception and **not** catching it.

You can simply throw the exception outside a try/catch block.